# getLastKnownLocation returns null

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I've read some questions about this, but I didn't quite find an answer that I needed.

So, the case is that I have my map set up, and I want to grab my current gps location.
I have checked that my variables is not NULL but yet my result from:

```
getLastKnownLocation(provider, false);
```

Gives me null though, so this is where I need help.
I have added permissions for COARSE + FINE location. But I usually have all kinds of network data disabled for my phone, because I'm not very happy about unpredictable dataflow expenses in my phone bill. So I have only WiFi enabled and connected for this test.

Is there anything more I NEED to enable in order for this to be possible? I would think WiFi should be sufficient?

Comment: you are mixing new api and old for getLastLocation follow this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48033659/4997704

Comment: This answer is worth reading : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794291/5319831

Comment: In my case, I was testing on Emulator.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Use this method to get the last known location:

```
LocationManager mLocationManager;
Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
    Location bestLocation = null;
    for (String provider : providers) {
        Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (l == null) {
            continue;
        }
        if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
            // Found best last known location: %s", l);
            bestLocation = l;
        }
    }
    return bestLocation;
}
```

Comment: Turns out I had it correct all along, I just noticed an error that I found an solution to this. I did not have my phone set to allow Google Position for GPS. So, yeah. Thanks anyways =)

Comment: enable location in the phone.

Comment: question is about `getLastKnownLocation returns null` ... this code will change nothing ... if for all providers `mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation` **(as it can return null)**  it will still returns null ... **answer is ... sorry you cannot avoid this ... if you really want the location do not use getLastKnownLocation**

Comment: I was calling it from service class and faced nullPointer on getApplicationContext(). So using context of the activity class solved my problem.

Comment: It should be `l.getAccuracy() > bestLocation.getAccuracy()`.

Comment: without enable gps how to get lastknownlocation?

Comment: Perfectly worked for me. Just need to have permissions wrapper.

Comment: Worth reading this answer, if the code doesn't work for you : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38794291/5319831

Answer (score 33):

you are mixing the new and the old location API's together when you shouldnt.

to get the last known location all your have to do is call

```
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1"
mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
```

once the location service was connected.

read how to use the new location API

http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html#GetLocation

```
 private void getLastLocationNewMethod(){
    FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    // GPS location can be null if GPS is switched off
                    if (location != null) {
                        getAddress(location);
                    }
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.d("MapDemoActivity", "Error trying to get last GPS location");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that there is new API. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: thank you so much this API is much faster thanks man i didn't knew it exists

Comment: Location returns null in here as well. What can be the reason?

Comment: check Location permission

Comment: Agreed... this should be the accepted answer. Thank you.

Comment: @BineshKumar I am using this API in my android app to get the current location of user on button click. But the location in onSuccess is always null. I have also turned on my phone's GPS.

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to get the cached location from the Network Provider. You have to wait for a few minutes till you get a valid fix. Since the Network Provider's cache is empty, you are obviously getting a null there..

Comment: Alright, so I need my cache building up?
How can I do that when my app crashes because of this?

Comment: you have to use the onLocationChanged method of the location listener. Getting a valid fix takes time (few minutes)

Comment: Alright, thanks. I'll fiddle around until I see it popping a log =)

Comment: Do I need to move around with it even if it has nothing stored?

Answer (score 1):

Add this code

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
     return;
}
```

**before** the function:

`locationManagerObject.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, new LocationListener())` 
as well as the function: `locationManagerObject.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this it works good for me :-

```
LocationManager mLocationManager;
Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();

        private Location getLastKnownLocation() {
            Location oldLoc;
            while (true){
                oldLoc = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (oldLoc == null){
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return oldLoc;
        }
```

You can use NETWORK_PROVIDER in place of GPS_PROVIDER for faster results..

Answer (score 1):

```
private void getLastLocation()
{
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);


    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.e("location",location.getLatitude()+"");

        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,locationListener,null);

}
```

// This will help you for fetching location after gps enable

> locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,locationListener,null);

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Xamarin.Android.

`Location location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);` was returning null value. I checked my code and got to know that I had just requested permission for ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION. I added code to request permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and now it was not returning null. Here is my code:

```
void AskPermissions()
{
    if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted ||
            CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) != (int)Permission.Granted)
        RequestPermissions(new string[] { Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation, Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation }, 0);
    else
        GetLocation();
}

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation) == (int)Permission.Granted &&
            CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation) == (int)Permission.Granted)
        GetLocation();
    else
        Log.Info(tag, "Permission not Granted: Please enter desired Location manually.");
}

void GetLocation()
{
    locationManager = (LocationManager)GetSystemService(LocationService);
    provider = locationManager.GetBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);
    Location location = locationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(provider);
    if (location != null)
        Log.Info(tag, "Location Lat: " + location.Latitude + " Lon: " + location.Longitude);
    else
        Log.Info(tag, "Location is null");
}
```

In case anyone coming from Xamarin.Android (C#) would find it useful. For Java or Android Studio the code would be similar withs some minor Syntax changes like `GetLastKnownLocation()` will be `getLastKnownLocation()` as method names in Java start with lowercase letters while in C# method names start with Uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

I liked this solution to update location:

[Update location](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/f41897)

In resume, add the condition:

```
Location myLocation = getLastKnownLocation();
if (myLocation == null) {
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
      LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER,
      MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
      MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
      Log.d("GPS", "GPS Enabled");
 }
```

And maybe is some basic, but check that GPS is ON.

Answer (score -4):

Replace ur line with

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```