# LocationManager returns null longitude with getLastKnownLocation in Android

Tags: java, android, android-location

I have a code that is supposed to return the user location but the Longitude keeps returning `null` and as a result my app keeps crashing. How do I prevent this?

```
//get the user longitude and latitude
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();

Geocoder geocoder;  //return meaningful data from user location
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
```

Comment: Please post your error stacktrace

Comment: Null pointer exception on double longitude = location.getLongitude();

Comment: Your `location` is null, not your longitude.

Comment: `lm.getLastKnownLocation` could return null.

Comment: How can I handle this location should incase it returns null

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438627/getlastknownlocation-returns-null, this may answer your question.