# import com.android.internal.location.ProviderProperties; cannot resolve symbol 'providerproperties'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to get latitude and longitude using `GPSTracker` class, it always returns 0.

I traced the code, it took me to the `LocationManager` java file, it shows three imports with `Cannot resolve symbol` errors. Please see the picture below.

By the way, in the `GPSTracker` class, this line:

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
```

returns `null`, that's way I get 0 for latitude and longitude.

I can compile the code without any error.

much appreciated if someone could help.

[image: Can not resolve symbol]

Comment: The "GPS tracker" code has serious flaws which are discussed in [this blog post](http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/). Just choose some better example code (like from the [Documentation section](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/1837/location#t=201609041208362023868) here at StackOverflow and you'll have less troubles.

Answer (score 0):

for the second problem - getting null in getLastKnownLocation

use this solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20465781/6778400