# Latitude and Longitude is not displaying

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

I want to display Latitude,Longitude of current Location and display the name of the location from that latitude and longitude of that place in three textviews. But latitude and longitude value is not displaying in tv_lat and tv_long.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NetworkCallback, LocationListener {

private EditText empIdTxt;
private EditText passwordTxt;
private TextView tv_lat;
private TextView tv_long;
private TextView tv_place;
private Button loginBtn;
protected Location mLastLocation;
LocationManager locationmanager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    empIdTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_loginId);
    passwordTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_loginPass);
    tv_lat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_lat);
    tv_long = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_long);
    tv_place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_place);
    loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_login);

    empIdTxt.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(empIdTxt));
    passwordTxt.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(passwordTxt));

    empIdTxt.setText("vinay");
    passwordTxt.setText("qwerty");

    locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria cri = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(cri, false);
    if (provider != null & !provider.equals("")) {
        Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
        locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2000, 1, this);
        if(location!=null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"location not found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Provider is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

public void clickLogin(View v) {
    if (!validateEmpID()) {
        return;
    }
    if (!validatePassword()) {
        return;
    }

    LoginApi api = new LoginApi(this, this);
    api.processLogin(empIdTxt.getText().toString(), passwordTxt.getText().toString(),
            mLastLocation.getLatitude()+"",mLastLocation.getLongitude()+"",
            AlertDialogManager.todayDate(), new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this).getLocation()+"");
}

private void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}
private boolean validateEmpID() {
    if (empIdTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        empIdTxt.setError(ErrorUtil.USERNAME_ERROR);
        requestFocus(empIdTxt);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean validatePassword() {
    if (passwordTxt.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        passwordTxt.setError(ErrorUtil.PASSWORD_ERROR);
        requestFocus(passwordTxt);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.et_loginId:
                validateEmpID();
                break;
            case R.id.et_loginPass:
                validatePassword();
                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void updateScreen(String data, String tag) {

    if (tag.compareTo(ApiUtil.TAG_LOGIN) == 0) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Login Response"+data);

            JSONObject mainObj = new JSONObject(data);
            AppDelegate ctrl = AppDelegate.getInstance();

            if (!mainObj.isNull("username")) {
                ctrl.username = mainObj.getString("username");
            }
            if (!mainObj.isNull("password")) {
                ctrl.password = mainObj.getString("password");
            }

   /*         if (!mainObj.isNull("latitude")) {
                ctrl.password = mainObj.getString("latitude");
            }

            if (!mainObj.isNull("longitude")) {
                ctrl.password = mainObj.getString("longitude");
            }

            if (!mainObj.isNull("date_and_time")) {
                ctrl.password = mainObj.getString("date_and_time");
            }

            if (!mainObj.isNull("place")) {
                ctrl.password = mainObj.getString("place");
            }*/

            if (!mainObj.isNull("error")) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Fails",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Seems there is an issue please try again later",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }

}

@Override

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    tv_lat.setText("Latitude"+location.getLatitude());
    tv_long.setText("Longitude"+ location.getLongitude());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have given this permission in manifest & your gps should be turned on:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

In case if you are testing your application in marshmallow:

Give permissions programmatically.

Last thing is remove this condition from your code and run it. It will definitely work:

Remove this:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
```

If you find it is not working, I post my own class which is working perfect on `Lollipop` check it:

```
public class Google_Map_Current_Location extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
    GoogleMap googleMap;
    Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //show error dialog if GoolglePlayServices not available
        if (!isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            finish();
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.google_map_current_loction);
        SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment =
                (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.googleMap);
        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();
        try {
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            showSettingsAlert();
        }

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
        try {
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 20000, 0, this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView locationTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latlongLocation);
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        locationTv.setText("Latitude:" + latitude + ", Longitude:" + longitude);

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, 0).show();
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: In case you don't know how to give permissions programmatically. Write in comment. i'll update my answer with permissions.

Comment: I have added permission in manifest file,gps is on and i am testing my app in Lollipop.I have removed the condition.But after removing this I am getting the error "call requires permission which may be rejected by user,code should explicitly check to see if permission is available(with check permission) or explicitly handle a potential "SecurityException" "

Comment: I have solved the issue..in my case getLastKnownLocation() returned null..so i solved this with the help of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438627/getlastknownlocation-returns-null