# Android Logcat Error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, location

Good day!

I am currently experiencing a dilemma where my code works on one of my Android devices but force closes on the other one.

Based on the my logcat, this is the error:

```
02-27 06:37:29.134 23579-23579/com.example.maui.dabtrain E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                              at com.example.maui.dabtrain.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:504)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment$zza$1.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzt$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:507)
                                                                              at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.bw.a(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:82)
                                                                              at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.DynamiteModulesB:1805)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Here is the code for my location:

```
        gMap = googleMap;

        if(!gMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
            gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


        if (myLocation == null) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }


    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
    gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(userLocation, 13), 1500, null);
```

The rest of the code is for Google Markers, Polyline, Radius, etc.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: try read this, `mylocation` return null `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438627/getlastknownlocation-returns-null`

Comment: Duplicate of: [What is a NullPoiterException and how do I fix it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @Rotwang - may you please guide me on what to do? Thank you.

Comment: As with ALL NPEs, find the object you're referencing while it still has not been instanced. Instance it BEFORE using it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `getLastKnownLocation` is returned as `null`, if you look at the method

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)

> This can be done without starting the provider. Note that this location could be out-of-date, for example if the device was turned off and moved to another location.
>   If the provider is currently disabled, **null** is returned.

Having said that, you should always check for null when using `getLastKnownLocation`

Comment: Sorry, I'm so lost at the moment. So, what should I do now?

Comment: add `if(myLocation != null)` before `    LatLng userLocation = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
`

Comment: but it gives an error to my Location.distanceBetween if I do. That's why I removed the if(myLocation != null) statement in the first place. Haha!

Comment: put all code that uses `myLocation` under the `if` statement

Comment: I have tried this as well. I inserted it all under the if (myLocation != null) but all Google Markers, Polylines, Radius does not appear.