# get last known location in Android with GPS off

Tags: android, google-maps, location

I am using `LocationManager` to get the last known location. I found out that it returns null unless the GPS is turned on.

here is my code

```
mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        List<String> providers = mLocationManager.getProviders(true);
        Location bestLocation = null;
        for (String provider : providers) {
            @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Location l = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (l == null) {
                continue;
            }
            if (bestLocation == null || l.getAccuracy() < bestLocation.getAccuracy()) {
                // Found best last known location: %s", l);
                bestLocation = l;
            }
        }
```

is there any way to get last known location without needing to turn GPS on?

Comment: What about getfusedlocation?!

Comment: tried it and got null no matter GPS was on or off. then I copied this from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20438627/getlastknownlocation-returns-null